# scroll down by one line near the end of the file in less

Tags: less, scrolling

I have a file with really long lines that I am trying to view in `less`. If I am near the top of the file, I can arrow right or use `-S` (to disable line wrapping) and then press down arrow or `e` and it will move down by one line. But if I am near the end of the file, this doesn't work. It just says `END`.

I noticed that there is an `ESC-SPACE` shortcut to move by a page even if near the end of the file, but `ESC-e` doesn't work. So I have to use `-S` `ESC-SPACE` and then `UP ARROW` many times (being careful not to go too far!) to move down a line.

I also tried searching for a newline with `/\n` but that just searched for the letter `n` (`less --version` says it is compiled with POSIX regular expressions, maybe that is the problem).

Is there a simpler way to move down by a single line in less. I really would like for `RIGHT ARROW` `DOWN ARROW` to "just work" even if it is near the end of the file.

Comment: Sometimes I just use ´mcview´ which is a part of midnight commander as a workaround . You can wrap/unwrap, switch to hex view, etc. Maybe that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less` seems to support pressing `J` (i.e. shift+j) to always scroll one line, even when at the end of the file.  Conversely, `K` will always scroll the other way, even when at the top of the file.

I'm unable to determine out how I found this the first time!  If anyone has any pointers, would be good to see what other commands exist.

Comment: I found this in the less manpage: `J      Like j, but continues to scroll beyond the end of the file.`. It isn't mentioned in the less online help (`h`). I guess that help isn't exhaustive. It seems that both `K` and `Y` do this for the beginning of the file.